# Using thread and mutex in Android Studio with ndk 10c

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, gnu, build.gradle

I have the latest version of the 64bit NDK (r10c), and the latest version of Android Studio I can download (0.8.14).

I am making a number of JNI calls to use String, Vector, Atomic, etc. But I can not figure out how to use thread and mutex.

Both of them give me the same error

```
Error:(92, 5) error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(93, 5) error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
```

I'm sure that the NDK is using 4.9 of the gnu-libstdc++. If I put in a #error in the file I see my error and compilation stops. It appears that I'm not missing any defines since I can put the #error inside the class and see it.

Here is the ndk config in my build.gradle

```
ndk {
    moduleName "myLib"
    ldLibs "log"
    stl "gnustl_shared"
    cFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -pthread"
}
```

The -frtti and -pthread seem to make no difference. I have also tried stl of gnustl_shared as well as gnustl_static, no difference.

Answer (score 3):

By default, NDK still uses GCC 4.6 which has crippled support for C++11. You need the grade equivalent for setting `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=4.9` in **Application.mk**. You can find some answers here: *[how to specify NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION in gradle file for android ndk build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507780/how-to-specify-ndk-toolchain-version-in-gradle-file-for-android-ndk-build)*, but unfortunately the bottom line is that today you have to disable automatic **ndk-build** call by setting `jni.srcDirs` to empty and use the **Android.mk** and **Application.mk** files the old way.

So, if in your **jni** directory, there are files **file1.cpp** and **file2.cpp**, you will need the following **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH            := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE          := myLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES       := file1.cpp file2.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS          := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS          := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -pthread
```

... and **Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI               := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL               := gnustl_shared
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Comment: Are you sure it's 4.6 by default? I am pretty sure it's using 4.9 because when I edit the thread file in the 4.9 folder of the NDK I get build errors.

The article you cited, also states at the bottom that 64bit uses 4.9 by default now.

Comment: .. but you are not building for `APP_ABI=arm64-v8a`, are you?

Comment: No, but isn't it telling that if I edit the thread include file in 4.9 and the #error shows that I have determined which file is being included?  That comment was unclear to me if they meant the 64 bit version of the ndk, or a 64 bit build.

Comment: It's super easy to check. Run ndk-build from command line, and you will see the difference, or you won't.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you want me to do with a ndk build from the command line?

Comment: If you think that your build fails even though gcc 4.9 compiler is running, you can prove it by running this compiler (and 4.6, to compare) with ndk-build from command line. Or, use one of the _[solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk)_ that let you run `ndk-build` as a step of your gradle build.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to do the command line build? Or should I go with the initial link you sent?

I edited the 4.6 version of thread, and I see an error in there now, so it appears that it's trying to compile against both?

Comment: You don't need any link, simply put `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files in jni directory, and run `ndk-build` from command line.

Comment: What do I need to have in the Android.mk and Application.mk files? I have not done jni in Eclipse, so I'm learning both that and Gradle.  

I can run ndk-build '-C' filePath('{Full path to src dir?}')

Comment: `ndk-build -C "full path to src dir"` exactly. Check that `full_path_to_src_dir/jni/Android.mk` and `full_path_to_src_dir/jni/Application.mk` are there. You don't need `filePath()`.

Comment: But how do I generate the two mk files?